# A query regarding P vs NP

Tags: complexity-theory

**Problem Statement:** Given a Problem $(A)$ such that: Any proposed solution $(S_0)$ is guaranteed to be polynomial size w.r.t. $A$. Now, consider a fixed set of $K$ properties $\{k_0, k_1,...k_c\}$, where each property is $coNP-Complete$.

For any solution $S_0$ is considered a valid solution iff: "None of the property in $K$ has a $NO$ instance for $S_0$".

***Example:*** For some hypothetical problem $(A')$ let the solution $S_0'$ be a simple graph with $n$ nodes. Let $k_i$ be the property: "$S_0'$ does not contain  a clique with $n/4$ nodes".

**Query:** Assuming the highly improbable scenario that $P=NP$, it implies $P=NP=co-NP)$. Thus, all the properties in $K$ are $P-Complete$. Does that imply that finding the solution $(S_0)$ for $(A)$ is in $P$ ?
It seems so but still need confirmation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is essentially a $NP^{coNP}$ problem. If $P=NP$ then the [polynomial hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_hierarchy) collapses and your problem is in $P$.

If $P=NP=coNP$ then we can check in polynomial time whether a solution $S_0$ is valid (using a polynomial-time algorithm to check each property, which exists because $coNP=P$). Thus, the problem is in $NP$, and thus, in $P$.

Comment: thank you for confirming/clarifying.